# Youtube pause video full screen

Tags: youtube

Assuming that I am in a game that requires full screen and a YouTube video in chrome, but I am focused on the game, as I could pause the video of youtube with a combination of keys or something similar without having to remove the Game and back to chrome to pause it?

Comment: Most capture all input while you're in them. Some things, like volume controls on a keyboard, are allowed through to the system, but regular key commands are all run through the game when you're in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. At least not without some sort of software that could intercept a key combination and tell the browser to pause the video.